# onClick and onLoad change to addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css

html file:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset = "utf-8">
            <title>Image Slider</title>
            <link href = "slider.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css"> //link to css file
            <script src = "slider.js"></script>  //link to js file
        </head>

        <body onLoad = "photoA()">      //change to addEventListener
            <div id = "slider">
                <img src = "Images/img1.jpg" id = "image" >
                <div class = "left_hold"><img onClick = "photo(-1)" class = "left" src = "Images/arrow_left.png"></div>     //change to addEventListener
                <div class = "right_hold"><img onClick = "photo(1)" class = "right" src = "Images/arrow_right.png"></div>     //change to addEventListener
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

---

css file:
//styling web

```
*{
    margin:0px;
}

#slider {
    height:400px;
    width:650px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:4px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#image {
    height:400px;
    width:650px;
    position:absolute;
}

.left_hold {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.right_hold {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

.left {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:20px;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.right {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    right:20px;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.left_hold:hover .left {
    opacity:0.6;
}

.right_hold:hover .right {
    opacity:0.6;
}

.left:hover .left1
```

---

javascript file:

```
    var imageCount = 1;
    var total = 6;

    function photo(x) {
        var image = document.getElementById('image');
        imageCount = imageCount + x;

        if(imageCount > total){imageCount = 1;}
        if(imageCount < 1){imageCount = total;} 
        image.src = "Images/img"+ imageCount +".jpg";
        clearInterval(time);                                
        time =  window.setInterval(function photoA() {      


        var image = document.getElementById('image');
        imageCount = imageCount + 1;      //adding image 

        if(imageCount > total){imageCount = 1;}
        if(imageCount < 1){imageCount = total;} 
        image.src = "Images/img"+ imageCount +".jpg";
        },2000);         //time interval
        }

        var time = window.setInterval(function photoA() {    

        var image = document.getElementById('image');
        imageCount = imageCount + 1;

        if(imageCount > total){imageCount = 1;}
        if(imageCount < 1){imageCount = total;} 
        image.src = "Images/img"+ imageCount +".jpg";
        },2000);
```

---

Anyone can explain to me how to change the onLoad and onClick to addEventListener?
Do I need to change all the code again?
Or there is any simpler ways to do image slider without using jquery?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

Comment: The `<body onload...` is the same as binding to the `"load"` event of `window`, and the click event should be pretty obvious if you've read a tutorial. Did you try something that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    photoA();

    document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var target = e.target;

        if (target.tagName != 'IMG') return;

        var classList = target.classList,
            hasLeftClass = classList.contains('left'),
            hasRightClass = classList.contains('right');

        if (hasLeftClass || hasRightClass) photo(hasLeftClass? -1 : 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: He's currently binding to `window.onload`, which is probably a good idea since he's working with images. That way they'll be sure to be loaded before the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
left= document.getElementsByTagName('img');
left.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //do some things
});

right= document.getElementsByTagName('img');
left.addEventListener("load", function(){
    //do some things
});
```

use this demo

Comment: That'll fail. You should probably test your answer.